# String reversal function

Tags: c++, strings, homework

I have an assignment to create a function that reverses the letters of each word in a string individually. I feel like this should be a rather simple task. I did figure out a solution, although I feel like it uses too many variables as a sort of hack method. Any suggestions on how to make it more efficient/shorter?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>

using namespace std;

void rev(char str[80])
{
char t;
int l = 0, n = strlen(str), k = 0;

for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
{
    if (str[i] == ' ' || str[i] == '\0')
    {
        for (int j = i - 1; j > (k + i - 1) / 2; l++, j--)
        {
            t = str[j];
            str[j] = str[l];
            str[l] = t;
        }
        k = i + 1;
        l = k;
    }
}

}

void main()
{
    char str[80];
    cout << "Please enter a string : ";
    cin.getline(str, 80);
    cout << "The original string is : " << str << "\n";
    rev(str);
    cout << "The new string is : " << str << "\n";
    system("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 6):

1. [`main` should be `int main()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/636829/difference-between-void-main-and-int-main)
2. Why C-style strings? Use `std::string`
3. One function - one task. You are mixing 2 things into one function:

   - Reverse chars in a word
   - Find words in a sentence separated by spaces

   I feel like your problem with too many variables will resolve when you split the tasks you are doing into separate functions.
4. Use better code formatting (auto-format).
5. Type mixing - [`strlen`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strlen)'s return value is `std::size_t`. Do not assign to `int`. As a follow-up, use a loop index of type `std::size_t` to match.
6. This is my preference - not using `using namespace std;` and `system("pause");`. I think a lot of posts could be found explaining why.

Comment: Disagree about the use of `std::string` - this assignment is a self-contained exercise, and a sequence of characters in memory is fine; the features of `std::string` are not useful here.

Comment: @einpoklum assignment is worded as "letters of each word in a string". String in C++ is represented by std::string. Where did you get a sequence of characters I do not know.

Comment: @einpoklum The size of the string in OP's code is hard coded. With `std::string`, you don't have that "problem".

Answer (score 3):

I'm just going to assume you cannot use `std::string` at all here, otherwise the code would be much shorter for learning purposes.

- If you have to use a fixed-size C-string, then you should *at least* make it much larger so that the input string won't likely overflow.  If that were to happen here, it would cause a buffer overflow. Otherwise, use a dynamically-allocated array to hold the correct size of the input string, while remembering to deallocate the array afterwards.

  ```
  char* str = new char[80];

  // reallocate and/or use as needed

  delete [] str;
  ```
- I don't think you need `<conio.h>`, especially in C++, so just remove it.
- It's usually preferred to put a space between `#include` and whatever is being included.
- This is not so clear at a glance:

  > ```
  > int l = 0, n = strlen(str), k = 0;
  > ```

  It's more preferred to have each variable declared or initialized on separate lines:

  ```
  int l = 0;
  int n = strlen(str);
  int k = 0;
  ```
- Do not use single-character variable names except for loop counter variables. It could be very hard for others to tell what they're used for, and even you may end up forgetting this after a while. If you're trying to achieve shorter but still good code, then this isn't really the way to do it.
- Instead of that manual swap code, you can just use [`std::swap()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap):

  ```
  std::swap(str[1], str[j]);
  ```
- Do not use `system("PAUSE")` to pause. It's not portable and uses more resources.  Instead, use something else that still acts as a pause, such as:

  ```
  std::cin.get();
  ```

  One difference is that this requires a character to be entered as opposed to proceeding right after the next keypress.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you separate the word reversal from the actual algorithm:

```
void reverse_string(char* start, char* end)
{
    char tmp;

    for (--end; start < end; ++start, --end)
    {
        tmp = *start;
        *start = *end;
        *end = tmp;
    }
}

void reverse_words(char* str)
{
    char* end_of_string = str + strlen(str);
    char* start_of_word = str;
    char* end_of_word = strchr(str, ' ');

    while (end_of_word)
    {
        reverse_string(start_of_word, end_of_word);
        start_of_word = end_of_word + 1;
        end_of_word = strchr(start_of_word, ' ');
    }

    reverse_string(start_of_word, end_of_string);
}
```